# MYSQL Wamp Server

Tags: mysql

please help me out in the following code its a syntax error but i don't understand where is the error i tried to run this trigger on Wamp server 
here is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Drivers_type_constraint BEFORE INSERT ON Cars
     FOR EACH ROW 
     BEGIN
        IF ((NEW.driver_name='null')||(NEW.driver_age<17)) THEN
             DELETE from Drivers where driver_id = NEW.driver_id;
        END IF;
     END;
     /
```

Error

```
you have an error in your SQL Syntax; Check the manual that correspond to your sql server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
```

If anyone want to suggest any idea it would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: So what error do you get?

Comment: "you have an error in your SQL Syntax; Check the manual that correspond to your sql server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8"

Comment: i am using wamp server actually

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error on MYSQL Trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659234/syntax-error-on-mysql-trigger)

Comment: So what is that stray `/` doing there in line 8? Is it meant as a delimited? Then where is that delimiter defined?

Comment: at line 5 actually it giving me the error